# export data from database in liquibase format

Tags: postgresql, grails, groovy, database-migration, liquibase

is it possible to export data in liquibase format from already exist postgresql database? until today i each time when i run my project in groovy grails i was using bootstrap file where i was generating everything to database. to export schemas i used `grails dbm-generate-changelog` and works fine. i used configure tutorial from http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/2.0.x/index.html

best regard!!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular SQL Dump from your DB in the liquibase migrations with minor effort:

1. Create your SQL file and put it under `grails-app/migrations`.  E.g.

   ```
   grails-app/migrations/2016-03-17-002-activiti-5.19.0.2.mysql.create.engine.sql
   ```
2. Add that file to your `changelog.groovy`
3. Add the following preamble to the SQL file

   ```
   --liquibase formatted sql
   ```
4. Separate your SQL file into sections you want to see as changesets (add at least one at the beginning):

   ```
   --changeset activiti:5.19.0.2-create-engine
   ```

See the docs: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html